# Hidden Markov Model in Tagging Problem

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language-processing, hidden-markov-models

I try to understand the details regarding using [Hidden Markov Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_model) in Tagging Problem.

The best concise description that I found is the [Course notes by Michal Collins](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~mcollins/hmms-spring2013.pdf).

The goal is to find a function $f(x)=arg max_{y \in Y} p(y|x)$, where $y$ is the tag set for sentence $x$.

**Question 1**. It's suggested to use a generative model and to estimate joint probability $p(x,y)$ from the trainig examples, however what the the reason to use generative model and increase the number of computation why not directly to estimate $p(y|x)$, I think it's possible to estimate the conditional probability straightforward from the training data.

**Addendum**. Do you know the reason why at all we should try to use a generative model in this case (POS tagging). As I  understand if we can estimate $p(x,y)$ that exactly with  the same success we can estimate $p(y|x)$  and directly find the answer to the question, what is the best tagging - $\hat{y}$ without weak assumption of generative model. There is the reason to use generative model, and I don't see it yet. Can you explain me what the reason?

**Question 2.** Assume we decided to use a generative model and made estimation to $p(x,y)$ why we decide to decompose it as follows $p(x,y)=p(y)p(x|y)$ and not  $p(x,y)=p(x)p(y|x)$?

**Addendum**. I do understand that it's very logical to use the decomposition $p(y)p(x|y)$ just because by doing it we approach $p(y|x)$, so mathematically it seems very reasonable, however according to the task I don't see what the problem to decompose it like $p(x,y)=p(x)p(y|x)$, there should be sore reason why we can not decompose it so and I don't understand why.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Could you edit your question to use complete sentences, and avoid run-on sentences?  I suggest you proofread the question, then click "edit" to revise it accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can directly estimate $p(y|x)$, this is what you're doing when using a Conditional Random Fields (CRF) for tagging. As someone else said, this is called a discriminative model. A major advantage of discriminative models for tagging is they allow one to easily incorporate arbitrary features (starts with a capital letter, contains a number, contains punctuation, etc). This isn't easy with generative models since doing so would usually violate the the independence assumptions required to make $p(x|y)$ tractable. Ultimately which one is better will depend on your particular problem.
2. If you're doing classification, and you can build a good model of $p(y|x)$, then what would you be messing with the joint for? When using a generative model for classification the idea is to "sneak up" on the distribution of interest, namely $p(y|x)$, because it is hard to model explicitly. One way to do this is by observing that $p(y|x) \varpropto p(y,x) = p(y)p(x|y)$.

Comment: thank you for your answer, as with MEMM model where it's possible to add arbitrary features, I wounder if there is possible at all to add some features except (previous tag for current tag, and current tag for word), the problem is in HMM I cannot think about features at all, for me it's just HMM assumption and Bayes. Can you show how to incorporate features to it?

Comment: Ironically I recently read a really neat paper covering this exact subject, [Painless Unsupervised Learning with Features](http://www.denero.org/content/pubs/naacl10_berg_painless.pdf). Although they focus on unsupervised learning, the techniques they use are would be applicable to supervised generative models as well.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer 1**

You *can* try to directly fit the function $\Pr[y | x]$. This is called a discriminative classification. This is typically solved via some regression mechanism such as ordinary least squares, or lasso, or ridge depending on certain assumptions of the model.

**Answer 2**

The reason we want to factor $\Pr[x, y] = \Pr[x | y] \Pr[y]$ is because we are interested in the *class conditional* density $\Pr[x | y]$. That is, what is the probability of observing data $x$ given the label $y$?

There are various pros and cons to both discriminative and generative classification. For example, generative models tend to be easier to fit [naive Bayes is maximized simply by counting, whereas discriminative requires solving some convex optimization problem]. However, discriminative models typically faire better under independence assumptions when fitting data.

Comment: Thank you very for your answer, I added an addendum, please take a look.