# Solving the part-of-speech tagging problem with HMM

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language-processing, hidden-markov-models

There is a famous [part-of-speech tagging problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Part-of-speech_tagging) in Natural Language Processing. The popular solution is to use [Hidden Markov Models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_model).

So that, given the sentence $x_1 \dots x_n$ we want to find the sequence of POS tags $y_1 \dots y_n$ such that $y_1 \dots y_n = \arg\max_{y_1 \dots y_n}p(Y,X)$.

By Bayes Theorem, $P(X,Y)=P(Y)P(X \mid Y)$.

Solving POS by HMM implies the assumptions: $p(y_i \mid y_{i-1})$ and $p(x_i \mid y_i)$.

The question is there are any particular reason why we prefere to solve it by generative model with a lot of assumption and not directly by estimating $P(Y \mid X)$, given the training corpus it's still possible to estimate $p(y_i \mid x_i)$.

The second question, even when we convinced that the generative model is preferred why to calculate is as $P(Y,X)=P(Y)P(X \mid Y)$ and not $P(X,Y)=P(X)P(Y \mid X)$. In case we have an appropriate generative story I can use $P(X,Y)=P(X)P(Y \mid X)$ as well, is it mentioned somewhere that assumed generative story is preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't this exactly the same question you asked [previously](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/16777/hidden-markov-model-in-tagging-problem)? I'll make some additional comments and add some links here. Hopefully that will help.

> is there are any particular reason why we prefere to solve it by generative model with a lot of assumption and not directly by estimating $P(Y∣X)$, given the training corpus it's still possible to estimate $p(y_i∣x_i)$?

It just depends. Choosing whether to model $P(X,Y)$ or $P(Y|X)$ is simply the choice of generative versus discriminative. Both have advantages. See the paper 
[On Discriminative vs. Generative classifiers](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~aarti/Class/10701/readings/NgJordanNIPS2001.pdf) by Ng and Jordan. One thing worth mentioning, that I didn't say last time, is unsupervised learning in a generative framework is normally straightforward. This means it is also fairly obvious how to do semi-supervised learning. Semi-supervised learning can be very helpful for NLP tasks where the amount of unlabeled data is essentially infinite and labelled data is hard to obtain. Semi-supervised learning is typically not as easy in a discriminative framework. See [Co-training](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Co-training) as an example of the later.

As for how one decomposes the joint, well that's up to you. There's no rule saying you cant decompose it as $P(X,Y) = P(X)P(Y|X)$. Doing so would be perfectly valid, just not sensible. Notice decomposing the joint this way includes the factor $P(Y|X)$ already. If you're ultimately interested in predictiong $Y$ given $X$, then you should should predict
$$
\begin{align*}
\arg\max_y P(Y=y,X=x) 
&= \arg\max_y P(X=x)P(Y=y|X=x) \\
&= \arg\max_y P(Y=y|X=x).
\end{align*}
$$
So you just use $P(Y|X)$ and ignore $P(X)$ and we're back at a discriminative classifier.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, yes it's the same question. Please take a look at the comment from the previous question.

Comment: @user16168 Why *did* you post the same question again?

Comment: @alto When you see a duplicate, please flag it as such.